# Error importing React component in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I am trying to test a basic react component with Jest but am getting an error when importing the component into my test. It works fine outside of my tests.

The error is:

Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

App.js

```
const App = () => (
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
)
```

app.test.js

```
import React from 'react'
import App from '../app'

test('App renders', () => {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Can you show your test code as well? It sounds like you're missing a DOM element for your component to mount to.

Comment: To be honest I don't have any code in my test at the moment as it appeared to be failing before it even got to it, ie the import

Comment: One potential issue: `App` is defined in `App.js` with a capital `A`, but is imported from `../app` with a lowercase `a`.

Comment: Does your `App.js` `export` the `App` function anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your config.js or package.json :

```js
    {
        "env": {
            "development": {
                "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
            },
            "test": {
                "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs", "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"],
                "presets": [
                    "@babel/preset-react"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```